# Spring Data JPA Join Query doesn't work with Pagination

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am facing issues with a Join fetch query when used along with Pageable. Below is the source code.

```
@Query(value = "select pa from parent pa join fetch pa.children ch where ch.status='ABC'", 
countQuery="select pa from parent pa join pa.children ch where ch.status='ABC'")
Page<Parent> getParents(Pageable pageable);


public class Parent{
private int id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private List<Child> child
.....getters/setters
}

public class Child{
private int id;
@ManyToOne)
@JoinColumn("parent_id")
private Parent parent;
.....getters/setters
}

@Bean("abcReader")
@StepScope
RepositoryItemReader<Parent> abcReader(
        AbcRepository abcRepository) {
    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Parent>()
            .name("abcReader")
            .repository(abcRepository)
            .methodName("getParents")
            .pageSize(20)
            .sorts(Map.of("id", ASC))
            .build();
}
```

When getParents method is called then below exception is thrown

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: fromIndex(40) > toIndex(30)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]

After debugging, it appears that count query is not getting executed due to which JPA isn't able to understand how many records are present for the criteria and it keeps hitting the actual query and hence above exception is thrown. I am struggling to get this working. My use case is to fetch parent records by filtering child records in Spring batch Paginated reader and send it for processing.

Same query works fine if I remove pagination.

Comment: your count query isn't a count query?